# SemaphoreSlim SemaphorefullException is thrown

Tags: c#

For some reason i am getting the SemaphoreFullException when releasing the semaphore.
Could this be related to the ConfigureAwait(false) ?

Here is example code

```
 readonly SemaphoreSlim MODIFY_LOCK = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
 if (await MODIFY_LOCK.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.Zero).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            try
            {
                Remove(orderLine);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                MODIFY_LOCK.Release();
            }
        }
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: Sorry but this is the thing that this happens just in some cases and quite hard to reproduce, so thought that some expert might give an instant answer.

Comment: The docs show it executes sequentially. Did you try `Wait` instead?

Comment: no as i would not want it to block the thread, as i said it works in test environment but in some cases the exception is thrown in production.

Comment: `SemaphoreFullException` is thrown when you call `Release` on the semaphore too many times, do you call that anywhere else?

Comment: @DavidG Yes similar code block is executed elsewhere to sync access between multiple functions. The execution block is exactly the same as shown in code sample.

Comment: I bet that `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias technically you are probably right but i really cant understand why the error pops up :(

Comment: I would try catching the `SemaphoreFullException`, logging it, and basically ignoring it, and see what happens next.

Comment: Did you read the docs? `If the timeout is set to zero milliseconds, the method doesn't block. It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately.`

Comment: @NullReference mjwills is suggesting this: `if (MODIFY_LOCK.Wait(TimeSpan.Zero))`. May worth a try.

Comment: Sorry guys indeed i haven't even noticed that i use TimeSpan.Zero so yes you are right it would not block. So i will add some logging and try to figure it out.

Comment: Excellent. Let us know how `Wait` goes.